# Deploy Aurelia App using Azure App Service

Tags: visual-studio-code, aurelia

I'm trying to follow this instructions: https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/app-service-extension/deploy-app but when I click in the arrow or launch the command palette I don't see the "create new web app" option. I see "create new functionality app".
Any idea please?
regards

Comment: The link is down, could you provide some more information on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was That I had installed the App Azure Function extension instead Azure App Service Extension.

Thanks